# Ajax, selects and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have `fields_for` with select tags. I want to fill them dynamically. I mean: We choose country  (Ukraine in example) and then another select fills with name of the cities. So, I decided to make it with Ajax. Then we change 1 select's value it calls `OnClick` function, that uses Ajax to get values (cities) from my controller and fill 2nd select with them.

```
<%= f.fields_for :User do |f_cond| %>
<%= f_cond.select :country, countries %> #first
<%= f_cond.select :city, cities %> #second
```

Is it a good choice or I can make it better?

And will it be good to call some model's method directly from controller, or it will be better to make function in helper and call it?

Comment: It seems okay. btw, wht model method you have to call from controller in this case?

Comment: @Muntasim
Really in this selects I will put sorted and filtered values from User.column_names and other models column names. In example in first select I'll choose model name (User or smth) and second Ajax will fill with User.column_names. 
So this ModelName code (ModelName.column_names and filters) is better to write in controller or helper method?

Comment: could you please put your controller code here? You should use helper method to remove view complexities. Otherwise for processing data you should have a model method and you can call that from controller

Comment: @Muntasim my controller code was scaffolded with rails4. I was asking about "valid" (or "clean") code. I'll made ajax request to controller with model's name in params. I am going to make a method in it, that will catch ajax request and call method_names function from model, what was in params and will filter it from some values. After all of that it will return me an array with method names, that will fill my select tag.